# Conditional expectation with the condition being a range

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I can basically understand condition expectation with the condition being an event or a random variable($E(X|Y=y)$). However, I have a hard time understanding the condition being a range, especially with the variable itself or another random variable involved.

For example, $E(X|a<X<b)$, $E(X|Y>0)$, or $E(X|X>Y+a)$. What are the intution and formula behind?

I can roughly understand $E(X|a<X<b)$. We need to focus the value of $X$ between $a$ and $b$, so $\int_{a}^{b} xf(x)dx$. And because $(a,b)$ is just a subset of $X$, we need to scale $\int_{a}^{b} xf(x)dx$ by the probability of $X$ being in the range, so $E(X|a<X<b)=\int_{a}^{b} xf(x)dx/\int_{a}^{b} xdx$. Are the formula and understanding correct?

How about the other two?

Comment: Unfortunatelly you misunderstood the formula, as the $E(X|a<X<b) = \int_a^b x f(x) dx$. 

Think about the $X \sim Uniform(0,1)$. Your formula for $E(X|0<X<2)$ would give us $1 / 2$ which is clearly wrong.

Comment: More drastic example would be $X$ which comes from any distribution $E(X|-\infty<X<\infty)$

Comment: @vermator $E(X|a<X<b)=\int_a^b xf(x)\,dx\big/\int_a^bf(x)\,dx.$ What you wrote is equal to $E[X\cdot {\bf 1}(a<X<b)]$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Your right. I hurried up and didn't see my mistake. Look that in the question OP wrote $\int_a^b x dx$ instead of $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ in the denominator.

Comment: @vermator @@MikeEarnest $\int_{a}^{b} xdx$ is actually a typo... It should be $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$. Thanks for your answers. I have a much clearer understanding of this issue now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All three of your examples are of the form $E[X|A]$, where $A$ is an event with a nonzero probability. This is computed as
$$
E[X|A]=\frac{E[X\cdot {\bf 1}_A]}{P(A)}
$$
where $\def\1{{\bf 1}}\1_A$ is the indicator random variable for the event $A$.

The intuition is this: taking expected value is just integration. Taking conditional expected value is just a restricted integral over where you are conditioning on, and then dividing by a normalizing constant. Just like the expected value of a deterministic number is just itself, $E[3]=3$, you would hope the conditional expected value of a deterministic number to have the same property. Dividing by $P(A)$ in the above equation ensures this is so.

In order to compute $E[X\cdot {\bf 1}_A]$, you integrate $xf(x)$ only over the region $A$. When the event you are conditioning on involves another random variable $Y$, then the event is the region in the plane, and you must do a double integral over this region: $\iint_A xf(x,y)\,dx\,dy.$ On the other hand, $P(A)$ is found by just integrating the (joint) pdf over the region $A$.

For $E[X|a<X<b]$, you have erred in the denominator:
$$
E[X|a<X<b]=\frac{\int_a^b xf(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b\;\, f(x)\,dx}
$$
For your other two examples:
$$
E[X|Y>0]=
\frac
{\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x,y)\,dx\,dy}
{\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\;\,f(x,y)\,dx\,dy}
$$
$$
E[X|X>Y+a]=
\frac
{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{y+a}^{\infty}xf(x,y)\,dx\,dy}
{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y+a}^{\infty}\;\,f(x,y)\,dx\,dy}
$$

Comment: I don't really have a comment. Just found this while working on an actuarial probability problem and was really pleased at the clear exposition. Thanks for that!
(The closer we get to measure theoretic notation and rigorous mathematics, the happier I feel.)

Comment: Your answer is tremendous helpful for me. I've been stuck around similar question.   
 Just for simpler notation, let $E(X|a<X<b)=E(X|X\in B)$ we could rewrite in the *conditional density form* as $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\frac{f(x)\mathbf{1_B}(x)}{P(B)}dx$$, I am wondering if we could write similar *conditional density form* in the case $E(X|Y\in B)$? Much appreciated if you could reply.